# mod_rewrite SSL with other Rules Active

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I'm having issues with my mod_rewrite to SSL while keeping my other rules. I need all pages to be on SSL, but by adding the rule it created a redirect loop.

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteBase /

# Sign up
RewriteRule ^sign-up/$ /register.php [NC]
```

Where could I be going wrong here? I've tried changing the order of the riles but had no luck.

Cheers,
RJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. It turns out it was due to the web servers being behind a load balancer.

So, it took a while to find but if anyone else has a similar issue with multiple servers behind a load balancer, here is what you need:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks, RJ

Answer (score 1):

You need to exit the rewrite iteration with the `[L]` flag:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

# Sign up
RewriteRule ^sign-up/$ /register.php [NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, good answer. Unfortunately it didn't solve it, there is still a loop.